# Php Class Typehinting not working?

Tags: php

The code:

```
public function __construct(\Illuminate\Container\Container $app, RuleSetInterface $rules)
{
    $this->app   = $app;
    var_dump(is_null($rules));
    var_dump($rules instanceof RuleSetInterface);
    exit();
    $this->rules = $rules;
}

// This how it is called:
$form->setValidatorResolver(new IlluminateValidatorResolver($app, $form));
```

The Output:

```
boolean false
string '...\SubscriptionForm' (length=36)
boolean false
```

Here's how SubscriptionForm class is defined:

```
class SubscriptionForm extends AddressForm
class AddressForm extends Form
class Form
```

As you can see none of these implement the interface, so var_dump($rules instanceof RuleSetInterface); shows the truth, yet this code should cause a fatal error.

I am pretty sure PHP threw an exception saying that `$rules` is of unexpected type, expected RuleSetInterface. Am I missing something?

PHP Version 5.6.14-0+deb8u1

Comment: How do you call the constructor? Can you provide the code and exact value you pass as second argument? Is this using Laravel? Then maybe add that tag...

Comment: Can you show us how did you call this constructor? Also, if you call var_dump(get_class($rules)) as well, what do you get?

Comment: I have amended the question. This is not Laravel, just some components used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found the cause. It was custom error handler that suppressed the fatal error I was expecting.